# Why are the most frequent questions on the Scheme tag so lowly rated?

Tags: discussion, tags, upvotes

If we look at [the Scheme tag and order the questions by frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme?tab=frequent&pagesize=30), we see [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48064955/10319707) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18790192/10319707) [the](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20216711/10319707) top 30 with a number of upvotes in the single digits, despite many of its [highest voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme?tab=Votes) having triple-digit ratings. Why is this? In my experience, the rating of the top rated questions on any Stack Overflow tag tend to correlate strongly with the rating of the most frequent questions on that tag.

Comment: Have a look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172726/whats-the-frequent-sort-function.  The "Frequent" questions are the ones most commonly picked as duplicate targets for new questions.  In other words, these are the questions that are "frequently asked."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm aware of the difference. My question is about the absence of the correlation that I expected.

Comment: { shrug } People ask "What does `i++ + ++i` mean" on a daily basis, even though the question is completely uninteresting.

Comment: Also, it's probably worth noting that folks who ask these kinds of neophyte questions generally don't have enough reputation to upvote.

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's worse than uninteresting, it's reay, really bad code, even neglecting it's UBishness. Only profs on meth and tequila could possibly vomit out such madcademical code:(

Comment: The current most frequent question on Scheme ([Why exactly is eval evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2571401/2821954)) is linked from many `eval` questions on unrelated languages, like JavaScript, PHP... the concept is too generic that it also lost popularity compared to similar "eval is evil" question (in my case, [Google returned the Scheme question as the 4th result from SO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHiYw.png)).

Comment: I mean, there are so many of those 'ridiculous code' questions, all designed to highlight some language feature that any professional developer would avoid like the plague anyway.  I would nuke them all from orbit before they infect newbies and end up exploding out and covering terminals:((

Comment: On the other hand, the highest voted question on Scheme ([How is Racket different from Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3345397/2821954)) only has 6 other questions linked to it, because it's more specific to Scheme, popular (and "useful"), but not frequent since visitors can find it easier without asking the same question.

Comment: Unlike what one might have expected, [the view rate for Scheme questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/164178/highest-view-rate-questions-in-a-particular-tag-non-community-wiki) is ***not*** correlated with the number of votes. [#3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4092113) with about 14 views per day, only has 6 upvotes ([the top one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37774983) seems to be mistagged). [Screenshot](https://pmortensen.eu/temp2/HighestViewRate_SchemeQuestions_on_Stack_Overflow.png).

Comment: For comparison, [the current number one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956810) in terms [of view rate on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/120907/highest-view-rate-questions-non-community-wiki-4) (of all tags) has an (average) of about 2,600 views per day.

Comment: *#5 (not #3)...

Comment: View rate is probably a more honest measure (though it may also have positive feedback loops (making it somewhat random)).